How to chain find() methods and dealing with None in BeautifulSoup?
I am writing some HTML processing and am loving BS4.  I do find it a bit lengthy and was hoping there was some better way to deal with this.
I would love to chain my finds together like this:
soup.find('li', class_='positions').find('span', class_='list-value').getText()

Instead when the first find doesn’t find anything, it returns None and then the next find fails on that as expected.
I rewrote as two lines and it seems ok, but it would be preferred to have some sort of ?: conditional operator in there like I do in c#.
elem_sup_position = soup.find('li', class_='positions') 
sup_position = elem_sup_position.find('span', class_='list-value').getText() if elem_sup_position is not None else ''

I know I could probably rewrite it as this but I hate executing the first find twice to save 1 line of code!  Is there a slicker way to do this?  I have a lot of these.
sup_position = result.find('li', class_='positions').find('span', class_='list-value').getText() if result.find('li', class_='positions') else None


Hi, Could you please provide the html code you are aiming? It will help us understand your question better. Only your contents of your target tag (in this case <li>) should work.

@ShamsEShifat I don't see how that would help.  The question is not asking about specific html.

You could use css selectors to chain your selection:
soup.select_one('li.positions span.list-value')

and you could use the walrus operator (since Python 3.8) to avoid writing your selection twice:
result.getText() if (result := soup.select_one('li.positions span.list-value')) else None

Example
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li class="positions"><span class="list-value">some text</span></li>')

### your way with find
result.find('span', class_='list-value').getText() if (result := soup.find('li', class_='positions')) else None

### css selectors
result.getText() if (result := soup.select_one('li.positions span.list-value')) else None


Thank you!  I was stuck on Python 3.6 for a project so I hadn't even thought to advance to the latest for this one.  I am primarily a c#/javascript developer didn’t even know about the walrus operator, that is very slick and will reduce a lot of ugliness in my code.  The css selector method is perfect though with the double and triple checks I need.  Thank you!
